# Getting constant from a string

Tags: ruby

I got the following class structure:

```
class A
  class B
    class C
      module M
        MY_CONST = 1000
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to get the constant `MY_CONST` from a string `"MY_CONST"`. I tried `M.const_get("MY_CONST")` but it doesn't seem to work. Says `NameError, wrong constant name`. Am trying to do this within the `module M`. What am I missing?

Comment: your module should be `M` not `m`, How can you access it as `m`? I think `A::B::C::M.const_get('MY_CONST')` should work.

Comment: Sorry, the name of the module does start with a Caps. Was a typo.

Comment: what is the exact message you get and in what ruby version are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was doing something really stupid. I was trying to get the name of the method from `caller[]` but was getting the entire path and didn't regex filter the name of the constant. There is nothing wrong with the way I was trying to derive the constant.

Answer (score 0):

If the module name was in fact `M` and not `m`, the following works in `irb` for Ruby 2.0:

```
irb(main):009:0> class A
irb(main):010:1> class B
irb(main):011:2> class C
irb(main):012:3> module M
irb(main):013:4> MY_CONST = 1000
irb(main):014:4> end
irb(main):015:3> end
irb(main):016:2> end
irb(main):017:1> end
=> 1000
irb(main):018:0> M.const_get("MY_CONST")
=> 1000
irb(main):019:0>
```

Ruby 1.8.7 does give the `NameError: uninitialized constant M` error, however, unless you fully qualify the module name:

```
A::B::C::M.const_get("MY_CONST")
=> 1000
```